# Java Generics - Unexpected bounds

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, bounds

No Problems here

```
public class MyList<E extends Number> extends ArrayList<E> {
}
```

.

Unexcepted bound. What does this mean? And why is it wrong? Thanks for help.

```
public class MyList<E extends Number> extends ArrayList<E extends Number> {

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain when exactly you are getting this error ? Is this compilation error ? Or it's coming while instantiating this class or what ?

Comment: compilation error

Answer (score 7):

`class MyList<E extends Number>` is OK because you *declare* a type parameter, so you have to give it a name (`E`) and you can optionally declare it as bounded (`extends Number`).

In `extends ArrayList<E>` instead you just have to "use" a type parameter: with "`<E>`" you refer to the parameter declared in your class, for which a bound is *already* given in its declaration. "`<? extends Number>`" (with `?` in place of `E`) would also be accepted by the compiler (although it would be not what you want). Instead, "`<E extends Number>`" is taken as a type parameter declaration, so it is a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyList<E extends Number> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1025575227555594680L;

}
```

This should work with no compilation error and no warnings even. Let me know if you still have the same error.